# Difference between var and const in document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript

When I store `document.getElementById` in `var` I can't change `innerText`

```
var status = document.getElementById('status');

// This doesn't work (nothing changes in the element)
function change() {
    status.innerText = "Ready.";
}
```

But when I store it in `const` I can. Why?

```
const status = document.getElementById('status');

// This works
function change() {
    status.innerText = "Ready.";
}
```

Comment: Try using a different name for the variable. The `var` declaration affects the global scope (the `window`), and if there is a collision with a native browser window property, it will cause your code to behave as you are observing.

Comment: @Pointy yup, that was indeed the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elements declared with `var` on the top level get assigned to the global object. When you do `var status =`, you assign to `window.status` - but `window.status` [is reserved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) and [must always be a string](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#dom-window-status). So, the result of `document.getElementById('status');` is converted into a string when assigned.

Variables declared with `const`, in contrast, do not get assigned to the global object when on the top level, so the problems with `window.status` do not appear.

Another solution would be to write your code inside an IIFE:

```
(() => {
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  function change() {
    status.innerText = "Ready.";
  }
})();
```

Or use a different variable name than `status`.